# Android Facebook Login Works, but Endlessly Stuck on Login Screen

Tags: android, facebook

I have a Facebook login on my Android app, and it successfully logs you in, but once logged in, it stays on the Login Button screen. In other words, after tapping the "Login to Facebook" button and logging in with your account, you're stuck in an endless loop of logging in. I'm not getting any errors on output, so my attempts to debug so far have been unsuccessful...some help would be appreciated.

```
 private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private static final int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter;
    private TextView info;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final View mainActivity = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        View loginButtonLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.login_button, null);
        setContentView(mainActivity);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        //If there is no account associated with user, follow this loop
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
            FacebookSdk.setApplicationId(getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_app_id));
            setContentView(loginButtonLayout);
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
            loginButton = (LoginButton) loginButtonLayout.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
            loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // Start sign in/sign up activity
                    setContentView(mainActivity);
                    startActivityForResult(
                            AuthUI.getInstance()
                                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                    .build(),
                            SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE
                    );
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again later.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again later.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        } else {
            // User is already signed in. Therefore, display a welcome message
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch the request and process the result on onActivityResult()

Comment: What would that look like (sorry if this is stupid question, I'm a little ignorant of Android)

Comment: Something like: @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

Comment: Where would I put that and call that, though? I get an error because I can't put Override in the main because it's an annotation